# What does OP mean?

Tags: discussion

So, I was recently looking around at the comments on some of my questions, and I saw multiple references to "the OP."

What does this mean?

Comment: _Originalis Postis_ (Original Post in Latin).

Comment: I happen to know Latin, and the correct translation is actually *Post originale*

Comment: originalni poster — original poster in Croatian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Original Poster**](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/op/). Aka "the author of the thing we are commenting on". In an answer, or in comments on a question, it will refer to the author of the question. In comments on an answer, it will refer to the author of the answer.

Comment: "*In comments on an answer, it will refer to the author of the answer.*" not always. Sometimes it will still refer to the question asker. Usually when aimed at the answer writer. So, if I were to say "Hey, KeizerHarm - your answer doesn't conform to the OP's requirements" that OP is not *you*. (also, to be clear, your answer is fine) Just be a bit mindful about the context - it's usually clear what's meant.

Comment: I've encountered people who say OP means "Original Post," referring to the body of text and not the person. For example, "referring to the edits you've made, I think the OP makes much more sense. Roll the edits back." Though I personally always thought it original poster.

Comment: @KeizerHarm : Thanks, I really appreciate the answer; it makes complete sense. +1.

Comment: @BMFForMonica -- I use it both ways. Context will generally make clear which is meant, though sometimes the actual referent is ambiguous.

Comment: I just have to throw this out there.  I know that it refers to Original Post, but in some of the questions it makes me think of "Over Powered"  as in "Superman is seriously OP and it makes it hard to come up with new and unique situations"  In a lot of questions and answers, certain things are seriously Over Powered making it difficult to solve the problem